# Need some advice for nginx, git and jenkins

Tags: git, docker, nginx, jenkins, devops

I recently started a project for learning more about DevOps practices. I developed a django app and wanna write technical posts in my app. My website is ready to publish but I have some questions. 
I dockerized my app and working with docker-compose but I don't wanna waste time for nginx so I want to dockerize that too.

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    build: .
    image: dockerdjangoexample
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn fatihkocnet.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/fatihkocnet
      - ./fatihkocnet/career/static:/static
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/fatihkocnet
      - ./fatihkocnet/career/static:/static
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Nginx part is not working right now. Still trying to configure this but I have another problems too. I think, without production and development env. I cannot easily use nginx while developing. It will never work properly. So I thought I can use jenkins and git. Meanwhile, I want to share my project to other people with MIT Licence. Then I realised I can't. Because in the source code I use my production password, usernames etc.

MAIN QUESTIONS: How can I create production and development environments. Is it just using of git? Or I need to create whole new infrastructure? How can I develop free software without giving everyone my passwords. Can I crypt them in Github? 
I think production and development environments will solve my problem. I see everyone says that but what are those? What they mean by that? Is it about git branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rule: **do not commit passwords to source control**.

Second rule: do not hard-code host names, user names, or passwords in your application’s source code.

In general, try to follow the [12 factor application](https://12factor.net/) pattern.

The whole point of “development”, “staging”, and “production” environments is that you can run the same application source code in multiple places with different setups.  For example, my day-to-day development workflow looks like this:

1. I do development locally, with no Docker involved at all.  All of my database host names are `localhost`, and the passwords are `password`.  I develop, run local tests, launch the service, and test until I think it works.
2. I build Docker images of my component and deploy it locally.  This might be to a local Docker Compose setup, where the database host name is `database` and the password is `password`.
3. I commit to source control and push it to a branch.  My coworkers review it.
4. Our CI system (Jenkins as it happens) builds my component, runs its tests, and deploys it to a test environment.  There is an actual database host name and a password that Jenkins injects.
5. If this is all good and the combined system works in the test environment, I merge my branch and tell Jenkins to deploy to the production environment.  This uses a non-Docker database with a real hostname, and a password that Jenkins injects.

So: sometimes I run things in Docker; sometimes I don’t; the same application code works both places.  I am not overly concerned that one environment might use a different patch release of a language runtime than another, and explicitly declare my library dependencies (`package.json`, `Gemfile`, `setup.py`/`requirements.txt`, *etc.*).  I pass in host names and credentials via environment variables, and these are the only differences between environments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I will working on Jenkins. But I have still questions. How can I manage nginx? Do I still need to dockerize it or just running in the server will solve my problem?

Comment: Running a mix of Docker and non-Docker parts is fine, if that's what works in your environment.